# Prevent Record Type from being Created

Tags: apex, trigger

I've got 2 objects , Parent Object & Child Object.
Parent Object has 2 record types, Record type A and Record type B.
Child object has 2 record types, Record type 1 and Record type 2.

I want to set up an a situation where a parent record has record type A, it should only be able to have a child record of record type 1 (Child records with record type 2 should not be created).

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) apex trigger on Parent object, that checks on update if it has child object and if combination of new Parent Record- Child Record is allowed 2) apex trigger insert, update on Child object, than checks if combination of new Child Record - Parent Record is allowed. This is an idea!

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Just wanted to see if there was a way to do this without a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Validation rule on the child object which triggers if:
(RecordType.DeveloperName = "AX" && Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName != "BX") || (RecordType.DeveloperName = "AY" && Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName != "BY")

This will cover child creation scenarios, and attempts to change the child record type. What it won't do is cover attempts to change the parent record type when it already has children. (Would that be a common scenario?)

Also it won't help with the fact that a profile can only have one default record type for creating the child. A Quick Action (Lightning) or JS Button (Classic) that pre-sets the child record type may be able to help with that - use two different actions for two different record types and put them on the appropriate parent layouts.